# How to install RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: nautilus, 15.04, gedit, svn, rabbitvcs

I'm looking for an SVN GUI that integrates into the file browser (Nautilus or Thunar). So far I've only found RabbitVCS for this, but I'm having trouble installing it. Yes, there are plenty of posts here about this, with plenty of tips, and I think I've tried them all - no success.

Here are my steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-cli
```

All of this executes fine, but then this line fails:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3
[...]
E: Package 'rabbitvcs-nautilus3' has no installation candidate
```

So instead I do:

```
sudo apt-get install -y rabbitvcs-nautilus
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib/
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1 /usr/lib/
wget http://rabbitvcs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/nautilus-3.0/RabbitVCS.py  /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config/rabbitvcs
killall nautilus
```

I end with a system that correctly shows the overlay icons and correctly works on the CLI, but when I right-click any folder, the entry "RabbitVCS" is simply missing.

(It's also terribly annoying that the "clock icon" overlay is displayed on *every damn file on my entire system* - I only want overlays on actually versioned files.)

- Is something broken with 15.04, or what is going on here? What did I miss? What did I do wrong?
- Also, the gedit plugin seems to malfunction. When I try to [enable the plugin in gedit](http://www.ubuntujourneyman.com/2011/08/10/rabbitvcs-in-gedit/) by ticking the checkbox, the checkbox disappears and the plugin icon is replaced by a red stop sign.

Answer (score 4):

The PPA [ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) doesn't contain Vivid packages. Therefore you can't install `rabbitvcs` via this PPA.

[image]

---

`rabbitvcs-nautilus` is also in the [Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/rabbitvcs-nautilus)

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

Output of `apt-cache policy rabbitvcs-nautilus`

```
rabbitvcs-nautilus:
  Installed: 0.16-1
  Candidate: 0.16-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.16-1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.16-1~getdeb1 0
        500 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ vivid-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
```

---

To install rabbitvcs in Vivid you could use also use the [GetDeb](http://www.getdeb.net) repositories:

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu vivid-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus-3.0
```

Comment: Is there a third line missing in your answer? Once I've added getdeb to that .list file, what's next? I found that I could now do `sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus-3.0` (not sure whether that "-3.0" is new due to your answer), and after I did a `killall nautilus && nautilus` I still did not have any new items in my right-click menu -- but I do have those icon overlays I mentioned above. I feel that there's a step missing that I haven't discovered yet.