# How to upgrade from rabbitvcs 0.15 to 0.16?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, software-installation, ppa, rabbitvcs

How to upgrade from rabbitvcs 0.15 to 0.16 in ubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you using? 14.04? Have you added the PPA?

Comment: @ron ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
```

Now, update the sources by:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install it with;

```
sudo apt-get install «packages»
```

where package:

- `rabbitvcs-nautilus3` for the Nautilus 3.x extension
- `rabbitvcs-nautilus` for the Nautilus 2.x extension
- `rabbitvcs-thunar` for the Thunar extensions
- `rabbitvcs-gedit` for the GEdit extension
- `rabbitvcs-cli` for the command line launchers

There are no packages for Ubuntu 15.04 in the PPA. If you are using 15.04, follow the instructions given in [How to install RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646109/how-to-install-rabbitvcs-on-ubuntu-15-04) to install `rabbitvcs`.

Comment: i m able to upgrade by following ur instructions,after performing all these steps terminal message is - rabbitvcs is latest version.But  when i m checking manually in UI its still 0.15.

Comment: @shi You can also try to install manually by downloading the `.deb` files from [here](https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) or from the tarball as described [here](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.10 and lower, simply run :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the steps above and the **rabbitvcs > about** in the nautilus ui still showed the old version.

To fix this I did the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove rabbitvcs-nautilus3
sudo apt-get remove rabbitvcs-core
nautilus -q
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-core
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3
```